# How to retrieve formatted values of lookups in an entity?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

We are facing challenge in getting formatted values of lookups available in an entity using web api.

**Scenario**: we have an entity with 8 lookups. When I'm querying those with Web API, getting GUIDs of those lookups, but not the names of those lookups.

Comment: Could you please share your code? your question is not clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396&tduid=(64775fcac148bf2afd151793e3fb90e7)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-XqaW0OY9doiYjZYkaSqUMg)()#Retrieve%20data%20about%20lookup%20properties)  says adding header in web api request `Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"` will result you the formatted value - Name, logical name along with Id like below: (without making another call)

```
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
```

-

```
   "_customerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty":"customerid_contact",
   "_customerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"contact",
   "_customerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Susanna Stubberod (sample)",
   "_customerid_value":"7ddd0b31-ed8b-e511-80d2-00155d2a68d4",
```

Comment: Hi Arun, would this work in CRM version 9? I heard going further completely OData calls get deprecated. But i will try this approach you have suggested anyway and get back to you. Thank you for prompt response.

Comment: OrganizationData.svc is deprecating not odata/webapi

Answer (score -2):

You can not retrieve formatted values in WebApi. you should retrieve your lookup name or any other detail(field) by a second call and retrieve name or any field of lookup using its GUID

Comment: It’s not true. You can include annotation header to fetch Name in single call. $expand fetch other fields as well..

Comment: Yes, we can get formatted values... adding this - `req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");`  helps us in getting formatted values of look-ups in single go.